# How does $1.88x < z <2x$ imply $z>6$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, integers

If $z, x$ are positive integers, does $1.88 x< z <2x$ impliy $z>6$?

I found this in a paper. I notice $x > 8$ for $z$ to be integer.

How does $1.88x < z <2x$ imply $z>6$?

Comment: Start with small values of $x$. Can you find an integer in the open interval $(1.88, 2)$? In $(3.76, 4)$? Then you should see the idea (and find the solution quickly).

Comment: That is an easy elementary approach, but a bit brute-forceish and doesn't extend well to a larger problem.  What if it was $1.9999999x<z<2x$ instead and the claim was that $z>10000$... I wouldn't want to check each interval manually one at a time until I rule out all possibilities.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Emphasis on “see the idea” :)

Comment: "I notice x>8 for z to be integer" and "How does 1.88x<z<2x imply z>6?"  The answer is because "I notice x>8 for z to be integer".   $z > 1.88x > 1.88\cdot 8 = 15.04 > 6$ w

Comment: Okay... I have to ask why you are asking if $z> 6$.  We've proven $z> 15$ so why was $z > 6$ asked? Was that a necessary condition for something else that needed to be shown?

Answer (score 7):

EDITED: Let $y = 2 x - z$.  Then $y$ is an integer, and $y > 0$ so $y \ge 1$.
But $y < 2 x - 1.88 x = 0.12 x$ so $x > y/0.12 = 25 y/3 \ge 25/3$, and
that says $x \ge \lceil 25/3\rceil = 9$.  And then $z > 1.88 x \ge 16.92$ so $z \ge 17$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $y<2x-1.88x=0.12x$?

Comment: Thanks for catching.  Edited.

Answer (score 4):

For $x$ integer also $2x$ is integer. The closest integer value smaller than $2x$ is $(2x-1)$ - but that must be greater than $1.88x$ for $z$ to fit required boundings.

So: $$1.88x < 2x-1$$ which implies $$x>\frac 1{2-1.88} = \frac 1{0.12}$$
Then $1.88x > \frac {1.88}{0.12} > 15,$ so $z>15,$ which implies $z>6$,
Q.E.D.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to show that $x$ must be at least $4$ so that $z >4(1.88)>6$. For this note that when $x=1,2$ or $3$ there is no integer between $(1.88)x$ and $2x$.

Comment: Your bounding $x\ge 4$ seems too weak. For $x=6$ there's no integer between $1.88\cdot 6=11.28$ and $2\cdot 6=12$, either!

Comment: True but I was only trying to prove what OP wanted. I could have gone further and found the smallest possible value of $z$.

Answer (score 2):

You've already essentially answered your own question, although the lower bound you give for $z$ seems somewhat arbitrary. You've already realised that $x \geq 9$, so you can easily substitute $9$ into the original inequality to obtain the lower bound for $x$, in this case $16.92 < z < 18 $, and the only integer solution of this is clearly $17$, which is strictly greater than $6$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be different.

$1.88 x <  z < 2x$

$1.8333333.... x= 1\frac 56 x< z < 2x$

$11x < 6z < 12x$.  Now as $3|6z$ and $3|12x$ inorder for $11x$ which is smaller then $12x$ to also be divisible by $3$ we must have $12x - 11x=x$ be a multiple of $3$.

If $x = 3$ then  $33 < 6z < 36$ and $5.5 < z < 6$ which is impossible.

So $11x$ is a multiple of $3$ that is larger than $33$ so $11x \ge 36$ so...

$36 \le 11x < 6z$.

So $z > 6$.  Which is *exactly* what you wanted!

But notice.....

This is a ***STUPID*** answer!

But I wonder if somehow something like this is why the value of $z>6$ rather than $z>15$ (which can *also* be proven) came up.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x\ge 1$, then $1.88x<z$ implies $z\ge 2$.

Then $z<2x$ implies $x\ge 2$.

Then $1.88x<z$ implies $z\ge 4$.

Then $z<2x$ implies $x\ge 3$.

Then $1.88x<z$ implies $z\ge 6$.

Then $z<2x$ implies $x\ge 4$.

Then $1.88x<z$ implies $z\ge 8$.

Can you continue?